# ENGLISH 220L keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I just dual-booted my laptop with Ubuntu and everything so far looks better than windows 10, but I was using a particular keyboard layout on windows named English 220L and I got really used to that for writing.My question is, can I somehow use that in Ubuntu?
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Comment: You'll have to tell us what it's for, and what release of Ubuntu you're using.  A quick search online tells me English 220L is an English Literature class for 2nd year secondary or tertiary students, but that may not be what you mean.

Comment: Related to your recent vandalism spree, if you eventually want to figure out how to constructively resolve the situation, probably start at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th